# How get coordinates of mouse click regardless of component viewport position

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, popover-position

I am trying to perform a classic piece of popover functionality where, when a user moves the mouse over a <div>, the popover should appear with information. Overall, things are working as can be seen in the image below.

[image]

How I am currently doing this is by getting the coordinates of where the mouse currently is positioned and then using those as a guide for where to position the popover. i.e.

```
this.hoverPositionTop = event.clientY;
this.hoverPositionLeft = event.clientX;
```

This all works great.....except when a user scrolls the viewport up. This is because the coords are based on the mouse position on the screen, not the <div>. So what happens is when I go to display the popover it appears further up the scrolled page as its placing it on to the page based on the PAGE coordinates, not the  coordinates.

[image]

So my question is - how do I get the correct coordinates of the mouse click such that the popover always displays at the mouse pointer regardless of whether the user scrolls the page or not?

Comment: Have you looked into [MouseEvent.pageX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX) and [MouseEvent.pageY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageY) instead?

Comment: Oh man. That absolutely solves my problem. I don't know how I couldn't figure that one out! Thank you sir! @MarkPond

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all kudos to @MarkPond who provided the answer in the comments above.

Have you looked into [MouseEvent.pageX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX) and [MouseEvent.pageY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageY) instead?

This resolved my question perfectly. See image below -

[image]